# How to import RSA public key as a string in dotnet core RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using `RSACryptoServiceProvider` in my dotnet project. I am importing public key from database and now I am trying to encrypt the symmetric key with public key for that I am using the code below:

```
public static byte[] GetKey(string publicKey)
{
     byte[] byteConverted = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(publicKey);
     var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
     rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(byteConverted, out _);
}
```

I am not getting errors but I found while dubbing that whenever the pointer came to import the RSA line then it never came back.

Comment: Hi @Saghar Francis, how do you invoke this static method? What do you mean for `the pointer came to import the RSA line then it never came back`?